# Visual studio Code (VSCode) disassembly view on MAC M1 doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, apple-m1, vscode-debugger

In **Visual Studio Code** on **Mac M1**, coding in **C++**, if I do a breakpoint and right click -> `Open disassembly view`, the highlighting of the code line doesn't work nor it doesn't follow the code when I click in `Step Into`.

According to [this official Microsoft post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-july-2021-update-disassembly-view-macro-expansion-and-windows-arm64-debugging/) it should work.

So, I don't know if it doesn't work because I'm using on a Macbook with M1 or is this some kind of bug or wtf?

Full Visual Studio has this functionality, unfortunately it doesn't support C++ on MacOS.

Comment: the blog post you linked to does say "windows arm64 debugging" not macos. Probably best to raise a feature request on the c++ plugin's github

Comment: that's true, but I thought it may be out of the box  with M1s too

Answer (score 0):

M1 mac versions are sometimes weird and require specific treatment. But in this case maybe its just not supported. Otherwise try installing some plugins for M1 mac on VS Code

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no plugins for Mac M1 :( At least, any I know of. And I checked the store. Do you have in mind anything in particular?
Can I somehow "emulate" x86 on mac m1?

Comment: in terminal arch -x86_64 /bin/bash for example

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to incorporate that into VScode workflow, so I can compile to x86 and view in VScode diassembly in x86?

btw, pozdrowienia! :)

Comment: ... or in Xcode?